# Through how many levels must cache writeback propagate?

Tags: concurrency, cpu-cache

Suppose that my multicore computer system has the diagrammed memory caches.

```
+---------+---------+-------------------+
| CPU 1   | CPU 2   | CPU 3   | CPU 4   |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Level 1 | Level 1 | Level 1 | Level 1 |
| cache   | cache   | cache   | cache   |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      Level 2      |      Level 2      |
|      cache        |      cache        |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|                Level 3                |
|                cache                  |
+-------------------^-------------------+
                    |
                    v
                   RAM
```

Consider a cache line CPU 1 has already loaded and written to, so that the cache line is already dirty in CPU 1's level-1 cache.

CPU 2 now writes to an address in the same cache line. What happens?

To maintain coherency from the perspective of CPUs 3 and 4, is the cache line in question automatically invalidated at level 1 *and* level 2? That is, does the system have to write the cache line all the way back to level 3? Or does writing it back to level 2 suffice?

If all the way back to level 3, then isn't level 2 pointless? (Surely the answer is *no,* but why?)

**REASON FOR THE QUESTION**

This question might interest other readers for various reasons, but I ask because I have been reading Intel's Software Developer's Manual and some interesting documents from the Linux kernel source. Those writings are telling me all about memory barriers, SFENCE/LFENCE instructions and the like; and I am trying to get all the relevant concepts straight in my head. Nevertheless, to the extent of my ability, I have tried to phrase the above question without tying the question to the x86 architecture. I ask today not for minute details of SFENCE/LFENCE, but rather ask for a brief conceptual orientation.

For information, so that you can pitch your answer at my level if you wish, I hold a master's degree in engineering but no C.S. degree.

Comment: It may help to lookup *cache coherence protocols*.

Comment: @Omar: most helpful. Thanks. Feel free to make your comment an *answer;* I would upvote.